# How to get a Google App Engine running locally

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to get a Python Google App Engine to run locally (macOS Sierra) and am having all sorts of trouble with and was wondering what I could possibly be missing. Please note this is my first foray into Python (usually develop with Ruby).

I've downloaded Google App Engine sdk for python and followed the steps to get it up and running. After a few attempts I've placed it within the same directory as my App.

I'm using Python 2.7.x which is what the App requires.

I'm using virtualenv so I've initiated it like so: `source bin/activate` and try to run the app like so: `dev_appserver.py --storage_path=../GAE-storage/ --port=9080 --log_level=info $* .`

When I try ti visit the page I get an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/wm/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "/Users/wm/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 354, in __getattr__
self._update_configs()
File "/Users/wm/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 290, in _update_configs
self._registry.initialize()
File "/Users/wm/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 165, in initialize
import_func(self._modname)
File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/python/flow.city/appengine_config.py", line 19, in <module>
from django.conf import settings
ImportError: No module named django.conf
INFO     2016-11-20 11:09:47,599 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

So, to fix this issue I've downloaded Django manually and extracted it to app directory. Then it complained I don't features, so I've also downloaded it manually and added to the project directory. Now is complaining about something else:

```
ERROR    2016-11-20 11:29:18,635 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/wm/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "/Users/wm/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 354, in __getattr__
self._update_configs()
File "/Users/wm/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 290, in _update_configs
self._registry.initialize()
File "/Users/wm/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/lib_config.py", line 165, in initialize
import_func(self._modname)
File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/python/flow.city/appengine_config.py", line 22, in <module>
import features
File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/python/flow.city/flowcity/features.py", line 23, in <module>
from base.basics import get_config
File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/python/flow.city/flowcity/base/basics.py", line 13, in <module>
from dbutils import date_to_str, rescale, get_app_url
File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/python/flow.city/flowcity/dbutils.py", line 23, in <module>
from i18n import _
File "/Library/WebServer/Documents/python/flow.city/flowcity/i18n.py", line 12, in <module>
from django.utils.translation import *
TypeError: Item in ``from list'' not a string
INFO     2016-11-20 11:29:18,641 module.py:788] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

So it makes me wonder if the approach I've taken is the right approach to get the App running locally? When cloning a new project in Ruby, I'd do a `bundle install` so it'd download all requirements for that project. Is there something similar in Python that I should do?

Please note that I've also tried without virtualenv and results were the same.

Comment: Post the contents of your app.yaml (minus the application ID if its in there).